# removeChild() is not defined

Tags: javascript, removechild

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function create() {
            var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
            var item = document.getElementById("toDo").value;
            paragraph.addEventListener("click", removeChild(paragraph));
            paragraph.innerHTML = item;
            document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
        }
    </script>
    <div>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <input type="text" id="toDo" placeholder="What To Do"><br>
        <button type ="button" onclick="create()">Add</button>
    </div>
```

I was creating a To-Do List and I was having problems with removing the item. I tried
setAttribute("onclick", removeChild(paragraph)) but that didn't seem to work. The error "removeChild is not defined" shows up every time. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do `paragraph.remove()`. `removeChild` is not a global function, it is a method. But `.remove()` is easier.

Comment: I tried multiple variations of that but they didn't work. It creates the paragraph, but doesn't get removed on click

Comment: Where is `removeChild` defined?

Comment: removeChild is a JS builtin

Comment: No, it is not a JS builtin. It is a *method* on Nodes, which is part of the DOM API.

Comment: Yeah, you're right

Comment: @Slick, please provide the relevant HTML, and even better would be to create a runnable snippet using the toolbar button in the editor. That way we can run your code and see what exactly doesn't work and why.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function create() {
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    var item = document.getElementById("toDo").value;
    paragraph.innerHTML = item;
    document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
    paragraph.addEventListener("click", function(){document.body.removeChild(paragraph)});
}
```

```html
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<input type="text" id="toDo" placeholder="What To Do"><br>
<button type ="button" onclick="create()">Add</button>
```

You also have to call `document.body.removeChild` instead of just `removeChild`.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced `paragraph` with `div` because I prefer `div` over everything in HTML, but the below code will work for both

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function create() {
    const pdiv = document.createElement("div");
    const item = document.getElementById("toDo").value;
    pdiv.addEventListener("click", () => {
      pdiv.remove();
    });
    pdiv.innerHTML = item;
    document.body.appendChild(pdiv);
  }
</script>
<div>
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <input type="text" id="toDo" placeholder="What To Do"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="create()">Add</button>
</div>
```